# Kulkarni-Nomizu product and identity on space of 2-forms

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, tensor-products, tensors

I am sure I am missing something stupid, but I have been on this for a while and I cannot get a factor of 2 right.

Let $E$ be a vector space with a non-degenerate quadratic form $q$. The Kulkarni-Nomizu product is the map $\bar\wedge: S^2E\times S^2E\rightarrow \Lambda^2 S^2 E$ given by
\begin{equation}
h\bar\wedge k 
= (h_{ac}k_{bd}+k_{ac}h_{bd}-h_{ad}k_{bc}-k_{ad}h_{bc}) e^a\otimes e^b\otimes e^c\otimes e^d
=\frac{1}{4}(h_{ac}k_{bd}+k_{ac}h_{bd}-h_{ad}k_{bc}-k_{ad}h_{bc}) (e^a\wedge e^b)\otimes (e^c\wedge e^d).
\end{equation}

It is well known that, making use of the isomorphism $\otimes ^2 (\Lambda^2 E) \simeq \mathrm{End}(\Lambda^2E)$ induced by $q$, \begin{equation}
\frac{1}{2}q\bar\wedge q=\mathrm{Id}_{\Lambda^2E}.
\end{equation} 
However I always get a factor of 2 wrong no matter how I compute it. For example, for $\alpha $ a 2-form,
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
\left( \frac{1}{2} q \bar\wedge q\right)  (\alpha)  &
=\left( (\delta _a^c  \delta_b^d  - \delta _a^d \delta_b^c ) e ^a \otimes e ^b \otimes e _c \otimes e _d\right)   \left(  \alpha _{m n } e ^m \otimes  e ^n \right) \\ &
= (\delta _a^c  \delta_b^d  - \delta _a^d \delta_b^c ) \alpha _{ mn }   \delta ^m _c  \delta ^n _d  \, e ^a \otimes   e ^b
= \alpha _{ cd }  \, (e ^c \otimes   e ^d- e ^d \otimes e ^c )
= \alpha _{ cd }  \, e ^c \wedge e ^d= 2 \alpha
\end{split}
\end{equation}

Where is the mistake?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the end, this seems to be just a matter of conventions in choosing the $q$-induced isomorphism $S^2\Lambda^2E \simeq \mathrm{End}(\Lambda^2 E)$. We get the right result by defining, for $T\in S^2\Lambda^2E $, $\alpha\in\Lambda^2E$ and denoting by $\tilde T$ the element associated to $T$ by the isomorphism,
\begin{equation}
\tilde T (\alpha) =\frac{1}{2} T_{abcd} \alpha_{rs} q^{rc}q^{sd}
=\frac{1}{2} T_{abcd} \alpha^{cd}.
\end{equation}
Since $T$ is symmetric in the interchange of first and second pair of indices it does not matter on which pair we contract with $\alpha$. The contracted indices are skew, so the factor 1/2 is actually quite natural.